# Merging sorted streams with conflict resolution

Tags: java, merge

Java question: I have 2 sorted streams: oldData and updatedData, sorted by say data.id. I want to merge them so if updatedData.id == oldData.id then updatedData will replace oldData.
There are existing libraries to do this, for example [Iterators.mergeSort](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#mergeSorted(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.util.Comparator)), but they allow output stream with dups, I did not find anything that takes resolver function to select "prefered" stream.

Another view on this problem: I want a merge function of the merge sort algorithm, that allows me to control cases when sorted objects are equal, i.e. which object to pick.

It's not a problem to write such code, but I would prefer to use something that is already written AND is part of widely used library like guava. Yes, I could do hacks like adding field data.isNew and post-filtering stream, or wrapping data in Pair(data, isNew), but I would prefer a cleaner solution.

I do not think this is a strange requirement for function merging streams, because standard [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) does exactly that: allows to resolve conflict between old value and new value.

Comment: A code snippet is worth more than thousands words :)

Comment: I'd like to do this (pseudo code): Iterator merged = mergeSort(sortedIterator1, sortedIterator2, comparator, dupResolver); However there might be other ways to achieve the same result, and I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Did you think of using [`Stream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)?

Comment: I do not think I can reliably control order in which objects with dup ids will  appear in the stream going to .distinct. It can be  oldData, newData, or newData, oldData. Even if I will find a way to control this order, I feel that it will result in fragile code: a subtle change can break it. Also I am not sure how .distinct knows that data are sorted. Most likely it  peeks into implementation of the stream. If it cannot discover that stream is sorted, it will assume unsorted and will try to sort it. I do not want that.